# flutter: wait for the navigation transition to end

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a kinda special use-case which is giving me headaches for hours now.

I do have an application which is using firebase and social logins for authentication. Additionally I implemented redux to manage the apps state.

Everything is working fine like this, but only when I try to logout while on a screen which needs data from the `FirebaseUser` class the rendering will fail, because the transition of the navigator is still running (triggers a rerendering of the screen I am navigating away from) and finally ends up in the desired place, but with a faulty screen while transitioning.

My middleware code for this is this:

```dart
Middleware<RootState> _signOutUser(GlobalKey navigatorKey) {
  return (Store<RootState> store, dynamic dynamicAction, NextDispatcher next) {
    final SignOut action = dynamicAction;
    final NavigatorState nav = navigatorKey.currentState;

    next(action);

    store.dispatch(AppIsLoading());

    Future<dynamic>(() async {
      try {
        await auth.signOut();
      } on PlatformException catch (error) {
        return Future<void>.error(error);
      }
    }).then<void>((dynamic _) {
      nav.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(Routes.home, (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
      store.dispatch(UnsetUser());
      store.dispatch(AppIsLoaded());
      action.completer.complete();
    }).catchError((Object response) {
      nav.maybePop(nav.context);
      action.completer.completeError(response);
      store.dispatch(AppIsLoaded());
    });
  };
}
```

I would ideally do it like this:

```dart
Middleware<RootState> _signOutUser(GlobalKey navigatorKey) {
  return (Store<RootState> store, dynamic dynamicAction, NextDispatcher next) {
    final SignOut action = dynamicAction;
    final NavigatorState nav = navigatorKey.currentState;

    next(action);

    store.dispatch(AppIsLoading());

    Future<dynamic>(() async {
      try {
        await auth.signOut();
      } on PlatformException catch (error) {
        return Future<void>.error(error);
      }
    }).then<void>((dynamic _) {
      return nav.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(Routes.home, (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
    }).then<void>((dynamic _) {
      store.dispatch(UnsetUser());
      store.dispatch(AppIsLoaded());
      action.completer.complete();
    }).catchError((Object response) {
      nav.maybePop(nav.context);
      action.completer.completeError(response);
      store.dispatch(AppIsLoaded());
    });
  };
}
```

But this way as well, the rendering while transitioning takes place.

I could just add guards to the screen, but that would result in a screen that is not looking like the one i was just viewing.

Or is there a way inside the widget to prevent re-rendering at a special event, so that it just stays the way it was?

I am kinda lost atm, so any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What I understand from your question is When you want to logout The App has to navigate to the home screen and after that navigation, you want to call some functions Am I right?

Comment: correct ... basically updating the store, but only **AFTER** the transition animation is done!

Comment: One more thing that is kinda strange, is that the method `pushNamedAndRemoveUntil` is never entering the `then`, `catchError` or even `whenComplete`.

Comment: I think It must return something maybe you couldn't catch [pushNamedAndRemoveUntil](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushNamedAndRemoveUntil.html)

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution ... and it is apparently a bug in the `flutter` framework.

I dug around in the `Navigator` and `NavigatorState` classes of the flutter package and found the reason why the Future was never completed.

The method `pushNamedAndRemoveUntil` (as well as several others) do return a completer. So far it is (kinda) correct. But it only completes when the `Route` is popped from the stack. And that's incorrect behaviour.

As far as I am concerned it should complete when the new Route gets pushed to the stack (and the transition/animation did finish). There is actually a method present on the Route called `didPush` which returns a TickerFuture from the Animation:

```dart
TickerFuture didPush() => TickerFuture.complete();
```

This is as much as I would expect from a method like this.

For now I fixed it directly in the package, but will file an issue afterwards so that it can be fixed in the future.

Comment: The `pushNamedAndRemoveUntil` behaviour is consistent with the rest of the Navigator's push methods - they all return a Future, which resolves when that route is popped. The remove is synchronous (the method is not async, it only returns a Future), so you can act immediately after the call.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the [`completed`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TransitionRoute/completed.html) Future:

```dart
ModalRoute.of(context)!.completed.then((_) => print('Pop animation finished'));
```

PS: This obviously only works when you wrapped your Route in a `ModalRoute` e.g. `PageRoute` or `PopupRoute`.

Default `PageRoute`'s: `CupertinoPageRoute`, `MaterialPageRoute`, `PageRouteBuilder`

Default `PopupRoute`'s: `CupertinoModalPopupRoute`, `RawDialogRoute`

Answer (score 0):

As you have it right now, it can be quite tricky to get the desired result because you are awaiting for the sign out (where the `FirebaseUser` is removed) and only *then* pushing to the new screen.

The problem is that in the meantime, as soon as you remove the user, you'll still need some data on the current screen (I believe?) and you'll get an exception during the transition because you are trying to access data that isn't currently available. Am I right?

One easy solution (and perhaps the most correct one) is to let a reference to the user in the screen where you make the logout to live until the end of the its own life, thus, removing it only when disposing. We don't have access to your widget, but you can create a variable that gets the user reference and then signing out will sign out the user but you still have access to the previous data by that reference on your widget.

Another solution would be signing out only after pushing to the new screen, but you woulnd't be able to properly fallback if for some reason the sign out fails, however, typically this sign outs on the client side are made in a *best effort* approach, where it will always logout for the user, regardless of failing or not remotely. So, this way, you can simply remove the `await` from the `signOut` as it will end that method synchronously and call the sign out afterwards, or you can make it more explicitly like so:

```
   try {
      await nav.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
      Routes.home, (Route<dynamic> route) => false).then((_) => auth.signOut());
      store.dispatch(UnsetUser());
      store.dispatch(AppIsLoaded());
      action.completer.complete();
    } on PlatformException catch (error) {
      var response = await Future<void>.error(error);
      await nav.maybePop(nav.context);
      action.completer.completeError(response);
      store.dispatch(AppIsLoaded());
    }
```

Comment: It is not working ... and you made one assumption that is not quite right: I do only unset the user when the `auth.signOut()` succeeds, so that I am safe, when it might fail.

Problem is still there. And I think that the method `pushNamedAndRemoveUntil` is not correctly executed.

I tried runnig it like this (without all the store dispatches): `nav.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(Routes.home, (Route<dynamic> route) => false).then<void>((Object _) => print('#### THEN: CLEARED STACK')).catchError((dynamic error) => print('#### CATCH: DID NOT CLEAR STACK'));`

Comment: It is never entering either `then` or `catchError`.

Comment: Yes, it won't enter in the `catchError` like I said. That's one of the reasons this might not be the best solution if you really want to catch the error on logout. Is the `store.dispatch(UnsetUser());` being called at all?

Comment: Yes, it is. 

BTW: I found the reason why the future is (seamingly) never completed in the method. I will edit my post and file an issue with the flutter package.